# H2O GBM error in R: 404 not found (H2OKeyNotFoundArgumentException)

Tags: r, h2o, gbm

**When running,

```
h2o.gbm(y = "Y", nfolds = 3, ntrees = 100, training_frame = train, verbose = TRUE)
```

I receive the error:**

ERROR: Unexpected HTTP Status code: 404 Not Found (url = http://localhost:54321/3/Models/GBM_model_R_1504715033543_1)

```
water.exceptions.H2OKeyNotFoundArgumentException
 [1] "water.exceptions.H2OKeyNotFoundArgumentException: Object 'GBM_model_R_1504715033543_1' not found for argument: key"
 [2] "    water.api.ModelsHandler.getFromDKV(ModelsHandler.java:97)"
 [3] "    water.api.ModelsHandler.fetch(ModelsHandler.java:116)"
 [4] "    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)"
 [5] "    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)"
 [6] "    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)"
 [7] "    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)"
 [8] "    water.api.Handler.handle(Handler.java:63)"
 [9] "    water.api.RequestServer.serve(RequestServer.java:448)"
[10] "    water.api.RequestServer.doGeneric(RequestServer.java:297)"
[11] "    water.api.RequestServer.doGet(RequestServer.java:221)"
[12] "    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:735)"
[13] "    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)"
[14] "    org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684)"
[15] "    org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:503)"
[16] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)"
[17] "    org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:429)"
[18] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)"
[19] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)"
[20] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)"
[21] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)"
[22] "    water.JettyHTTPD$LoginHandler.handle(JettyHTTPD.java:183)"
[23] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)"
[24] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)"
[25] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)"
[26] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)"
[27] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handleRequest(BlockingHttpConnection.java:53)"
[28] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:971)"
[29] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1033)"
[30] "    org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:644)"
[31] "    org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)"
[32] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handle(BlockingHttpConnection.java:72)"
[33] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint.run(SocketConnector.java:264)"
[34] "    org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)"
[35] "    org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)"
[36] "    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)"
```

Error in .h2o.doSafeREST(h2oRestApiVersion = h2oRestApiVersion, urlSuffix = page,  :

---

Other details:

```
Starting H2O JVM and connecting: . Connection successful!

R is connected to the H2O cluster:
    H2O cluster uptime:         1 seconds 407 milliseconds
    H2O cluster version:        3.14.0.2
    H2O cluster version age:    15 days
    H2O cluster name:           H2O_started_from_R_root_bjy160
    H2O cluster total nodes:    1
    H2O cluster total memory:   6.98 GB
    H2O cluster total cores:    8
    H2O cluster allowed cores:  8
    H2O cluster healthy:        TRUE
    H2O Connection ip:          localhost
    H2O Connection port:        54321
    H2O Connection proxy:       NA
    H2O Internal Security:      FALSE
    H2O API Extensions:         XGBoost, Algos, AutoML, Core V3, Core V4
    R Version:                  R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
```

sessionInfo()

```
R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/libblas/libblas.so.3.6.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/lapack/liblapack.so.3.6.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1] h2o_3.14.0.2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.1 tools_3.4.1    RCurl_1.95-4.8 jsonlite_1.5   bitops_1.0-6
```

Suggestions?  Thank you

Comment: This appears to be a bug related to using `verbose` and `nfolds` at the same time. In the short term you can remove the `verbose` option and track progress by directing your browser to localhost:54321 and using H2O Flow.

Comment: Removing the verbose=TRUE fixed the bug.  thanks

Answer (score 0):

To officially answer this question, as Branden said above, this is a bug (and can be avoided by not setting the `verbose` option).  The bug is being tracked in the H2O-3 JIRA [here](https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-4885) and there is already a pull request with a fix [here](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/pull/1508).